# Visual Studio 2012 Installation gives error

Tags: windows-8, installation, visual-studio-2012

I'm having a problem with installing Visual Studio 2012 Premium (Professional and Ultimate too) under 64-bit Windows 8 Pro. When the 'acquiring' bar goes to 'Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Devenv' I get an error.

Here is the screenshot: 
[image: screenshot]

"Nie mozna odnalezc elementu" means "Can't find element."

And here is the log: 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/61787551/vs_log.txt

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try running the installer as administrator. (ie. Right click -> run as administrator)

Comment: if G:\ your DVD/mounted ISO drive? Is the ISo corrupted?

Comment: G:\ is mounted drive with VS iso, and check sum is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running the installer as Administrator. If it does not help delete Visual Studio from Program and Features and run CCleaner, then try and install Visual Studio 2012 again with Administrator rights. But before you do anything try and install all the **Windows 8 Updates** (Control Panel -> Windows Updates -> Check Updates).

Comment: Hi, I tryed this and still cant install ;/. I checked updates and installed all of them. Runned CCleaner and its still gives me that errors. I tried to install VS 2013 Preview and it works(!). Then i tried to install VS 2012 and still not work (with/out VS 2013 installed). Maybe its something wrong with Microsoft?

Comment: I do not think that something is wrong with Visual Studio 2012. Have you tried to find the denenv.exe file on your PC ? You should look where it is located and delete it. I think something is corrupted on your PC and that is why Visual Studio 2012 won't install. But if you can use Visual Studio 2013 than you are fine, it is better than 2012  even if it is a preview version. How many Windows Updates did you have to install ?

Comment: I haved to install about 20 updates (I haved auto updates turned off by accident ;/). Now I'll try to install it on another (clean) computer and post results here.

Comment: I think the problem is caused in the first place because of these 20 missing updates. Others had similar problems and reported that after updating windows, Visual Studio installed with no problems. Restart your PC, turn automatic Windows Updates ON, and check again for Windows Updates. If there are no Updates try once more to uninstall completely Visual Studio 2012, search the web how you can uninstall it completely/everything and then download Visual Studio 2012 again and run the installer with administrator rights. Hopefully you won't see the error anymore.

Comment: I tried to install it but it showing me 
"Unable to locate package source"
I can select "Download from the internet" or "Provide a location to search for the packages"
And this is path that comes up:
C:\Users\JA\Download\packages\vcRuntimeDebug_amd64\cab1.cab (the 'packages' folder does not exists)
When I select to download from the internet its showing up again after some time, I searched for "vcRuntimeDebug_amd64" folder but it doesn't contain "cab1.cab" file ;/.

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is, but from where are you installing Visual Studio ? Your problem might be now with the updates, try to download the update from here: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads#standalone
try also this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robcaron/archive/2012/11/26/how-to-install-visual-studio-2012-update-1-offline.aspx

Comment: Thanks to everybody for helping me. I managed to get rid of this :).
I runned CCleaner, cleared C://tmp and %temp%, absolutely removed VS and then installed it by downloading ISO image, checked sum - same as on site, burned its into dvd and installed :). It doesn't be able to find some component because it was searching in bad directory, when I burned it, it was searching for everything on disk so its finded every component. Now I have working Visual Studio 2012 Premium :).

Comment: @superpawelTV nice that you found the solution. Please mark my answer as accepted answer. And if you do not mind give me a +1  ;)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Visual Studio downloads (http://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs) and install Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows (from web or .iso)

This install also Blend for Visual Studio, but take care that require Windows 8.1, and from my experience will not install on the Preview (or trial) version of Windows 8.1.

Then you have to register Visual Studio Express with the 30 days of trial, in order to use it after this.

Hope it helps you.